# After invalidating session , it's still alive , why?

Tags: java, jsp, http, session, servlets

Consider the servlet :

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LogoutServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/loggingOut")
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        // Get the session
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        if(session != null){
            System.out.println("Here ...");
            session.invalidate();
            // forwards to the page logout.jsp
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/results/logoutResult.jsp").forward(request, response);
            // response.sendRedirect("./WEB-INF/results/logoutResult.jsp");

        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("There ...");
            // response.sendRedirect("error404.jsp");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("./WEB-INF/results/error404.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }


    }

}
```

After I invalidate the session and move to `logoutResult.jsp` , if I reach the above servlet again then the session is still "alive" , and I don't reach the code of `error404.jsp` , i.e. :

```
else
{
    System.out.println("There ...");
    // response.sendRedirect("error404.jsp");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("./WEB-INF/results/error404.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

How can I fix it ?

Much appreciated

Comment: because you are forwarding request to that jsp after invalidating session

Comment: It's not still alive. You have a new session.

Comment: You don't reach the code for error404.jsp because its under WEB-INF. Don't put JSPs under WEB-INF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `if(session != null){` means nothing here.  You should read an attribute from the session and check it for null:

```
   String username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");
   if(username!=null)
   {
      //user is logged in
   }
   else
   {
     //user is not logged in
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Because a new session is created every time you access the JSP. To disable this property put this directive :

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```